# Cannot create JavaFX project in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I've installed JDK 1.7.0_45.
I've got my JAVA_HOME system variable pointing to installation folder.
Typing java -version in comman line results in "java version "1.7.0_45" output.

I've got Eclipse Kepler with e(fx)clipse plugin.
In Eclipse, in "Installed JRE-s" tag I've added the new JDK and set is as default.

I clicked New -> JavaFX Project and filled Project name.
The only buttons available are "Back" and "Cancel". I don't see any errors.
The only other element available is "Configure" button in "JavaFX Runtime Configuration" section.
The section contains  message saying: "currently there are no configured runtimes".

I'm confused. I don't have a separate JavaFX runtime, and when I go here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html it points me to JDK 7 I've already downloaded with explanation that "JavaFX is co-bundled with JDK 7 for Windows, Mac and Linux, it contains all the latest features and security fixes."

What am I missing? How can I create a JavaFX project in Eclipse?

Comment: Java FX is in the jre/lib/jfxrt.jar file (relative to the JDK) or lib/jfxrt.jar (relative to the JRE).

Comment: Yes, it's there. However the only thing I can do in new JavaFX project wizard is "add a JavaFX SDK". If I try to point to JDK, JRE or JRE/lib directory, I get "Root directory doesn't contain path to profiles " message. I cannot point it to jfxrt.jar as "it's not a directory".

Comment: I installed the standalone JavaFX SDK and tried to add it to Eclipse. I still get the "Root directory doesn't contain path to profiles" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

I've uninstalled all plugins related to JavaFX (it turned out there were two of them) and then reinstalled e(fx)clipse from update site: http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-nightly/site.

Everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to add the 'jfxrt.jar' file to the path of your project. And it works! Is not necessary another plugins, just that.

P.D: It works for me on Mac OS with eclipse Kepler. In case it didn't work, install e(fx)clipse and try again.